# Check the file contents of a docker image

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am new to docker and I built my image with

`docker build -t mycontainer .`

The contents of my Dockerfile is

```
FROM python:3
COPY ./* /my-project/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD python /my-project/main.py
```

Here I get an error:

`Could not open requirements file: No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt'`

I am not sure if all the files from my local are actually copied to the image.

I want to inspect the contents of the image, is there any way I can do that?

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to get into the project directory and run the pip command.

The best way to do that is to set the `WORKDIR /my-project`!

This is the updated file

```
FROM python:3
COPY ./* /my-project/
WORKDIR /my-project
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD python /my-project/main.py
```

Kudos!

Comment: They are not. `ADD` can copy from URLs, whereas `COPY` cannot. `ADD` also has some rules that `COPY` does not. For more info, refer to the documentation https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy. But in this case, I do not see why `ADD` would be a solution over `COPY`.

Comment: The advice I've generally heard is that you should prefer `COPY` unless you specifically need to download an external URL or unpack a tar file, which `ADD` does.  This is also called out in [Best practices for writing Dockerfiles](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#add-or-copy) in the Docker docs.

Answer (score 3):

When you run `docker build`, it should print out a line like

```
Step 2/4 : COPY ./* /my-project/
 ---> 1254cdda0b83
```

That number is actually a valid image ID, and so you can get a debugging shell in that image

```
docker run --rm -it 1254cdda0b83 bash
```

In particular the place that container starts up will have the exact filesystem, environment variables (from `ENV` directives), current directory (`WORKDIR`), user (`USER`), and so on; directly typing in the next `RUN` command should get the same result as Docker running it itself.

(In this specific case, try running `pwd` and `ls -l` in the debugging shell; does your Dockerfile need a `WORKDIR` to tell the `pip` command where to run?)

Comment: This is helpful as well, thanks will check this also!